# To get the current $USER in LaTeX

Tags: latex

My friend has the following in his computer in a LaTeX document

```
 \includegraphics[width=13.0cm]{/Users/max/Dropbox/2_user_cases.png}
```

I would like to have a variable for the username such that we can collaborate faster.

**Pseudo-code about what I wont**

```
 \includegraphics[width=13.0cm]{/Users/`echo $USER`/Dropbox/2_user_cases.png}
```

**How can you have such an command inside LaTeX?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the graphicx package, you can define a folder for latex to look for all your images in, like this:

```
\graphicspath{{images/}}
```

In this particular configuration, latex looks for a folder in the same directory as your file called "images."

I don't see why you'd want to use a full path just to get image in...

Make a folder, put your .tex source file in there, create a folder for your images.

Stick you work in some sort of revision control system (git, SVN, etc etc.) 
Commit often, and you're on your way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I love your way of answering. You noted the source of the problem in the PATH which I did not know before.

Comment: you bet. I am a technical writer... and I am in LaTeX all day, almost 8 hours a day. :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can access envvars from LaTeX. As Rutger Nijlunsing has said, you can try "~/" since it is an alias to "/Users/<username>".

If there are other envvars that you need to access, my suggestion is using Makefile to 'compile' the .tex (or a shell script) calling [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to replace such word.

```
sed -i "s/max/$USER/" file.tex
latex file.tex
bibtex ...
latex ...
```

Answer (score 1):

use ~ for your homedirectory (which is probably /Users/$USER):

```
\includegraphics[width=13.0cm]{~/Dropbox/2_user_cases.png}
```

Comment: The tilde is definitely the best way for a home directory. What if it's not? The best I can come up with is to have the LaTeX document include another, which is generated from environment variables, and sets LaTeX ones properly. This could then be automated with a Makefile, which has a rule stating that the LaTeX output depends on the generated file. The rule for the generated file would call some user-created script...  bit kludgy but it'd work.

Comment: I cannot use ~ for some unknown reason. - Dropbox may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Do you have permission to view the other ones file?

Comment: I have permissions. Please, see Mica's answer for the solution to my question.